# Incrementing a character value in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I don't know how to do this. For example, my `al` register is holding letter "a" which is 0x41. If I want it to shift to the next character, let's say "b", can I do `inc al`?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Also you know that you can try to verify it.

Comment: Oh, my program still has some bugs, and I'm not that good at using the debugger in VS 2013, so I just want to make sure this is not one of them. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, 0x41 is 'A', not 'a'. Assembler requires you to be very precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this behavior in Visual Studio by writing a function which has a __asm{} block.

See more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz.aspx

the return value of the function will be in the `eax` register.

You can try something like:

```
int myFunction(){
  __asm{
      mov eax,0;  //make sure eax is 0 since it will be the return value
      mov al,0x61;  //add "a"
      inc al;   //increment al, the return value is here in al(eax)
  }
}
```

And as far as I remember(since I used asm long time ago) yes, `inc al` will get you to the next character which is "b" in your case.

The processor does not know if you have a character or reference there, it will just see numbers. Therefore all you do is to increment a numeric value. In this case the char `a` is *0x61*, and the char `b` is *0x62*.
Also,  the processor does not know there is a char, the char is the way how you chose to print.

**Note:** You can also use this to isolate some of your other problems you encounter for debugging them easier.

You can find on the MSDN documentation about how to get the function parameters with an inline `asm` block here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5sds75we.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `'a' + 1 == 'b'`.  This works in asm too.